# Как вывести всю информацию из первой таблицы?

Tags: html, django

Есть 2 класса: Товар (Item) и Тип товара (ItemType). Я связал их при помощи 'ForeignKey'.
Я хочу чтобы при выборе одной категории товара, выводился весь товар этой категории (делаю фильтр для интернет магазина )
Вопросы:
1)Правильно ли я связал две таблицы?
2) Как делать запрос, чтобы вывести весь товар одной категории

```html
#models.py

class Item(models.Model):

    item_title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=200)
    item_description = models.TextField('Описание')
    item_size = models.CharField('Размер', max_length=10)
    item_price = models.IntegerField('Цена')
    item_pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публицкации', auto_now=True)
    item_image_1 = models.ImageField('Первая картинка', upload_to="images", null=True)
    item_image_2 = models.ImageField('Вторая картинка', upload_to="images", null=True)
    item_color = MultiSelectField('Цвета', max_length= 100, choices=colors, null=True)
    item_type = models.ForeignKey('ItemType', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)

    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name= 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товар'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.item_title)
    
class ItemType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название товара', max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= 'Тип товара'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Тип товара'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

**view**

```
item_type = ItemType.objects.get(id=1)
```

**html**

```
{% for item in item_type.item_set.all %}
    {{ item.item_title }}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```